# Set Priority in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am working with selenium webdriver. I have written 2 methods

1) addUserWithOutFirstName()
2) addUserWithOutGeneratingLicenceKey()

Initially the priority was set 0 for addUserWithOutFirstName() and 1 for addUserWithOutGeneratingLicenceKey(). Now i want to change the priority of addUserWithOutGeneratingLicenceKey() as 0 and addUserWithOutFirstName() as 1. I have changed the priorities. But still addUserWithOutFirstName() is getting executed first.

Don't know what is the problem. Can anybody help?

/* Add user without generating licence key */

```
@Test(priority=0)
public void addUserWithOutGeneratingLicenceKey() throws BiffException, IOException,InterruptedException {

    try {
        int successfullLoginRowNumber = 6;
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement username = webElement("VAR_EMAIL");
        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys(getCellContent(0, successfullLoginRowNumber));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement password = webElement("VAR_PASSWORD");
        password.clear();
        password.sendKeys(getCellContent(1, successfullLoginRowNumber));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement signInButton = webElement("VAR_SIGNINBUTTON");
        signInButton.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        input(properties.getProperty("VAR_ADDUSERDETAILS"));
        int emptyLicenceKeyRowNumber = 1;
        WebElement firstName = webElement("VAR_FIRSTNAME");
        firstName.clear();
        firstName.sendKeys(getCellContent(0, emptyLicenceKeyRowNumber));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement lastName = webElement("VAR_LASTNAME");
        lastName.clear();
        lastName.sendKeys(getCellContent(1, emptyLicenceKeyRowNumber));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement email = webElement("VAR_ADDUSEREMAIL");
        email.clear();
        email.sendKeys(getCellContent(2, emptyLicenceKeyRowNumber));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement countryCode = webElement("VAR_COUNTRYCODE");
        countryCode.clear();
        countryCode.sendKeys(getCellContent(3, emptyLicenceKeyRowNumber));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement phoneNumber = webElement("VAR_PHONENUMBER");
        phoneNumber.clear();
        phoneNumber.sendKeys(getCellContent(4, emptyLicenceKeyRowNumber));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        List<WebElement> allUserTypes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='add_user']/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/label"));
        for (WebElement ele : allUserTypes) {
            String userType = ele.getText();
            String user= getCellContent(5, emptyLicenceKeyRowNumber);
            if (userType == user) {
                ele.click();
                break;
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        List<WebElement> allCountry = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='add_user']/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div/label"));
        for (WebElement ele : allCountry) {
            String country = ele.getText();
            String cntry= getCellContent(6, emptyLicenceKeyRowNumber);
            if (country == cntry) {
                ele.click();
                break;
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement organization = webElement("VAR_ORGANIZATION");
        organization.clear();
        organization.sendKeys(getCellContent(7, emptyLicenceKeyRowNumber));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        List<WebElement> allDomains = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='add_user']/div/div[7]/div[2]/div/div/div/label"));
        for (WebElement ele : allDomains) {
            String domain = ele.getText();
            String dmn= getCellContent(8, emptyLicenceKeyRowNumber);
            if (domain == dmn) {
                ele.click();
                break;
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement licenceKey = webElement("VAR_LICENCEKEY");
        licenceKey.click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        if (driver.findElement(By.className("disabled")) != null) {
            testresultdata.put("14", new Object[] { 13d, "Add User","Add User without generating licence key","Should not be possible to add user","Should not be possible to add user", "Pass" });
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (driver.findElement(By.className("disabled")) == null) {
            testresultdata.put("14", new Object[] { 13d, "Add User","Add User without generating licence key","Should not be possible to add user", "Possible to add user","Fail", e.getMessage() });
        }
    }
}


/* Add user without entering first name */

@Test(priority=1)
public void addUserWithOutFirstName() throws BiffException, IOException,InterruptedException {

    try {
        int successfullLoginRowNumber = 6;
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement username = webElement("VAR_EMAIL");
        username.clear();
        username.sendKeys(getCellContent(0, successfullLoginRowNumber));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement password = webElement("VAR_PASSWORD");
        password.clear();
        password.sendKeys(getCellContent(1, successfullLoginRowNumber));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement signInButton = webElement("VAR_SIGNINBUTTON");
        signInButton.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        input(properties.getProperty("VAR_ADDUSERDETAILS"));
        int emptyFirstNameRowNumber = 2;
        WebElement addUser = webElement("VAR_ADDUSER");
        addUser.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement firstName = webElement("VAR_FIRSTNAME");
        firstName.clear();
        firstName.sendKeys(getCellContent(0, emptyFirstNameRowNumber));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement lastName = webElement("VAR_LASTNAME");
        lastName.clear();
        lastName.sendKeys(getCellContent(1, emptyFirstNameRowNumber));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement email = webElement("VAR_ADDUSEREMAIL");
        email.clear();
        email.sendKeys(getCellContent(2, emptyFirstNameRowNumber));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement countryCode = webElement("VAR_COUNTRYCODE");
        countryCode.clear();
        countryCode.sendKeys(getCellContent(3, emptyFirstNameRowNumber));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement phoneNumber = webElement("VAR_PHONENUMBER");
        phoneNumber.clear();
        phoneNumber.sendKeys(getCellContent(4, emptyFirstNameRowNumber));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        List<WebElement> allUserTypes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='add_user']/div/div[5]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/label"));
        for (WebElement ele : allUserTypes) {
            String userType = ele.getText();
            String user= getCellContent(5, emptyFirstNameRowNumber);
            if (userType.equals(user)) {
                ele.click();
                break;
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        List<WebElement> allCountry = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='add_user']/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div/label"));
        for (WebElement ele : allCountry) {
            String country = ele.getText();
            String cntry= getCellContent(6, emptyFirstNameRowNumber);
            if (country.equals(cntry)) {
                ele.click();
                break;
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement organization = webElement("VAR_ORGANIZATION");
        organization.clear();
        organization.sendKeys(getCellContent(7, emptyFirstNameRowNumber));
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        List<WebElement> allDomains = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='add_user']/div/div[7]/div[2]/div/div/div/label"));
        for (WebElement ele : allDomains) {
            String domain = ele.getText();
            String dmn= getCellContent(8, emptyFirstNameRowNumber);
            if (domain.equals(dmn)) {
                ele.click();
                break;
            }
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        WebElement licenceKey = webElement("VAR_LICENCEKEY");
        licenceKey.click();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='add_user']/div/div[9]/div/div")) != null) {
            testresultdata.put("14", new Object[] { 13d, "Add User","Add User without entering first name","Should not be possible to add user","Should not be possible to add user", "Pass" });
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='add_user']/div/div[9]/div/div")) == null) {
            testresultdata.put("14", new Object[] { 13d, "Add User","Add User without entering first name","Should not be possible to add user", "Possible to add user","Fail", e.getMessage() });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share code of it so it can show clear picture of it

Comment: Code is updated in the question

Comment: @kushal Answer should work. If it doesn't can you share your testng.xml & update your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse > goto Project > Clean > select your project.

Then select your testng.xml > run as TestNG Suite.

Comment: you just now typed my answer :)

Comment: Well I'm fast ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of priority, you should try to use **dependsOnMethods**.

Following code will help you :

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class DependencyAnnotation {

   @Test(dependsOnMethods = { "addUserWithOutFirstName" })
   public void addUserWithOutGeneratingLicenceKey() {
      System.out.println("Inside addUserWithOutGeneratingLicenceKey");
    }

   @Test
   public void addUserWithOutFirstName() {
      System.out.println("This is addUserWithOutFirstName");
   }
}
```

Then check for **testng.xml** file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1">
   <test name="test1">
      <classes>
         <class name="DependencyAnnotation" />
      </classes>
   </test>
</suite>
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

> Don't use priority=0.

For me @Test(priority=1) and @Test(priority=2) work as intended.

Then if you want further control of your tests you can add the dependsOnMethods combined with the priority

```
@Test (priority=1)
public void method1(){
}

@Test (priority=2, dependsOnMethods="method1")
public void method2(){
}

@Test (priority=3, dependsOnMethods="method2")
public void method3(){
}

@Test (priority=4)
public void method4(){
}
```

In the example above all methods 1-4 will be executed sequentially. If for some reason methods 1 fails, then methods 2 will be **skipped** (as it depends on Method #1). Similarly method #3 will be skipped as well (as it depends on #2).
Finally, in the event of #1 failing, the next method to be executed will be 4.

- 1-FAIL
- 2-SKIPPED
- 3-SKIPPED
- 4-RUN